# is it possible to set the UILabel distance between the Letters?

Tags: iphone

is it possible to set a  distance between the Letters like a b c

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you could do by using the `StringWithFormat` or `initWithFormat`  function of `NSString`.

Do something like below ..

```
NSString* myString = [[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"%@ %@ %@",@"a",@"b",@"c"];
```

Assign **myString** to your label.

Comment: That works for full-sized spaces, which is definitely something, but is rarely what you want when attempting complex typesetting. In the example you give it would be much easier to simply set the string to `@"a b c"`. If you had an existing arbitrary string and wanted full-sized spaces you'd likely be better off by creating a new string by iterating through the characters in the existing string and appending each one and a space character to the new string -- using `initWithFormat` (or better, the convenience method `stringWithFormat` means you need a custom line of code for every string.

Answer (score 0):

Neither UILabel nor the UIFont you set it to have character spacing options. There's likely a way to do with with [Core Text](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/StringsTextFonts/Conceptual/CoreText_Programming/Introduction/Introduction.html), but a quick look through the framework documentation didn't reveal it.